# Get TransactionIDs and join in a array

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Hello I'm making two requests on google analytics and I would like to get id transactions of the lines that had transactions

**Example return:**

```
[
    "source" => "google"
    "medium" => "cpc"
    "adwordsCampaignID" => "11297081171"
    "adContent" => "(not set)"
    "adwordsCreativeID" => "471314201447"
    "sessions" => "1266"
    "bounceRate" => "71.24802527646129"
    "avgSessionDuration" => "30.337282780410742"
    "pageviewsPerSession" => "1.24565560821485"
    "goalConversionRateAll" => "1.263823064770932"
    "goalValueAll" => "0.0"
    "goalCompletionsAll" => "16"
    "transactions" => "2" <<<<<<<<<<<<< how does get transactionid of this and join with this array
    "transactionRevenue" => "980.0"
  ]
```

return I would like:

```
[
    "source" => "google"
    "medium" => "cpc"
    "adwordsCampaignID" => "11297081171"
    "adContent" => "(not set)"
    "adwordsCreativeID" => "471314201447"
    "sessions" => "1264"
    "bounceRate" => "71.28164556962025"
    "avgSessionDuration" => "30.375"
    "pageviewsPerSession" => "1.2460443037974684"
    "goalConversionRateAll" => "1.2658227848101267"
    "goalValueAll" => "0.0"
    "goalCompletionsAll" => "16"
    "transactions" => "2"
    "transactionRevenue" => "980.0"
    "transactionIds" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "1148061790208-01"
      1 => "1148202732873-01"
 ]
```

**code:**

```
    /**
     *
     * @param Client $client
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAllAnalitcys(Client $client):void{

        try {

            $reportsWithAll = $this->getAnalitcysWithoutFilter( $client );
            $responseWithTransactions = $this->getAnalitcysWithTransactions( $client );
            $responseMerged = mergeAllWithTransaction($reportsWithAll, $responseWithTransactions);
            dd($responseMerged);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            throw new \Exception($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**First request:**

```
    /**
     *
     * @param Client $client
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAnalitcysWithoutFilter( Client $client ): array {

        $optParams['dimensions']  = 'ga:source,ga:medium,ga:adwordsCampaignID,ga:adContent,ga:adwordsCreativeID';
        $metrics = 'ga:sessions,ga:bounceRate,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:goalConversionRateAll,ga:goalValueAll,ga:goalCompletionsAll,ga:transactions,ga:transactionRevenue';
        return $this->getAnalitcys($optParams, $metrics, $client);

    }
```

Second request:

```
    /**
     *
     * @param Client $client
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAnalitcysWithTransactions( Client $client ): array{
        $optParams['dimensions']  = 'ga:source,ga:medium,ga:transactionId';
        $metrics = 'ga:totalValue,ga:revenuePerItem';
        return $this->getAnalitcys( $optParams, $metrics, $client);
    }
```

Method for making the requests in google analytics API

```
    /**
     * Obter relatórios do google analitcys
     * @param array $optParams Dimenções consultar na doc da api do analitcys
     * @param string $metrics Métricas consultar na doc da api do analitcys
     * @param Client $client
     * @return array|false
     */
    private function getAnalitcys(array $optParams, string $metrics, Client $client ): array {

        $dynamicAnalyticsKeys = $optParams['dimensions'].','.$metrics;
        $dynamicAnalyticsKeys = str_replace('ga:', '', $dynamicAnalyticsKeys);
        $arrAnalyticsKeys = explode(',', $dynamicAnalyticsKeys);


        $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = env('CREDENTIALS_PATH').'client_secrets.json';

        $googleClient = new Google_Client();
        $googleClient->setApplicationName("MeediaOnne");

        $googleClient->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
        $googleClient->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);

        $googleServiceAnalytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($googleClient);

        $resultGoogleAnalytics = $googleServiceAnalytics->data_ga->get( "ga:".$client->Analytics->config->id, '5daysAgo','today', $metrics, $optParams);


        if($resultGoogleAnalytics->getRows() > 0) {
            $results = $resultGoogleAnalytics->getRows();
            $reports = [];
            foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
                foreach ($result as $metric => $value) {
                    $report[$arrAnalyticsKeys[$metric]] = $value;
                }
                array_push($reports, $report);
            }
             return $reports;
        } else {
             return false;
        }
    }
```

this method does not function because the dimension source and medium do not make reference between the two requests

```
private function mergeAllWithTransaction( array $reportsWithAll, array $reportsWithTransactions ): array {
        foreach ( $reportsWithAll as $index => $paramAll) {
            if( $paramAll['transactions'] > 0 ) {
                foreach ( $reportsWithTransactions as $paramTransactions ) {
                    if( $paramAll['source'] == $paramTransactions['source'] &&
                        $paramAll['medium'] == $paramTransactions['medium'] )
                    {
                        $reportsWithAll[$index]['transactionIds'][] = $paramTransactions['transactionId'] ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $reportsWithAll;
    }
```